# Freebsd vs Mint( ubuntu derivatives)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-system, centos, freebsd

Since ubuntu has changed their interface so quickly, i am going to dive into either Mint or FreeBsd or event centos

I am developing php and ruby on rails run on linux, want to improve my bash script skills and know much more about web server

What's the best side of them ? Mint/FreeBsd/Centos

Comment: This is an opinion poll (as a development desktop, all of them are objectively equally viable), and off topic besides. (Also, neither BSD or CentOS are Ubuntu derivatives.)

Comment: I'm thinking of buying a new car. I have looked at both Audis and BMWs, but I can't decide which one I like better. They both have nice features. I'm thinking about doing a lot of driving on highways. Which one of those cars would be better for that?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin server! //any positive idea for centos or bsd ? i'v never used them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alot of that is preference, if your looking for a more complete OS with a nice GUI then Ubuntu or Mint. FreeBSD and CentOS are a little less polished on the front-end but very powerful, hence alot of web servers run CentOS.

Personally I also do LAMP development and I prefer an Ubuntu machine. It is very easy to setup a RUBY sandbox along with GIT using the Ubuntu software repository. You can read some more on the different distros here: http://distrowatch.com/

Answer (score 0):

from your question i believe you are willing to use a distro that will help you learn.
Hence i will suggest FreeBSD/CentOS.
If you only want to learn about web servers then go for CentOS but otherwise also have a look at ArchLinux.

Mint by default comes with a lot of pre-installed applications and is also done with a lot of new interface changes so in that way it is pretty similar to Ubuntu and wont solve your problems